# Serialization Apache Avro Generic Records using schema to File

Tags: java, avro

I have a code where I am trying to serialize List of Generic Records to Byte Array and eventually write that into File, but getting a UnresolvedUnionException

Listed below is the source code

```
public static byte[] encode(List<GenericRecord> records) throws IOException {
    Schema schema =
        new Schema.Parser()
            .parse(new File("schema.avsc"));
    SpecificDatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
    BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder = new EncoderFactory().binaryEncoder(byteArrayOutputStream, null);
    for (GenericRecord segment : records) {
      datumWriter.write(segment, binaryEncoder);
    }
    binaryEncoder.flush();
    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    Files.write(Path.of("file.avro"), bytes);
    return bytes;
  }
```

The error occurs where the field type is a record type, the code is able to parse successfully for primitive types string , int, but fails on type record